# Sorting/Ordering the contents of a jTable before committing to a bound Java DB

Tags: java, swing, jpa, jtable, jql

Is it possible to sort/order the contents of a jTable before committing to a bound Java DB?

Comment: there are two ways, 1. (better, faster, reason for why is there SQL engine) let it sorting in query on db size, 2. read oracle tutorial How to use Tables - Sorting and Filtering, then search here how to use SortKeys

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in java code too, I'm assuming you're using a `DefaultTableModel` as your model for your `JTable`

First get the data from the model, like this:

```
JTable grid =  new JTable(); //your grid to be persisted
DefaultTableModel model = grid.getModel(); //get the model (DefaultTableModel)
Vector vectorData = model.getDataVector(); //the data (Vector of vectors)
```

Then use the `sort()` method from `java.util.Collections` passing your `Comparator` to implement:

```
 public static final Comparator<Vector> COMPARATOR_BY_KEY = new Comparator<Vector>() {
    public int compare(Vector o1, Vector o2) {
        //Get the Column to be used as criteria for sorting
        //Need to be casted (cast to your real data type) as this is a Vector of Vectors 
        //In this example I'm assuming that cell data type is `String`
        String elementAtCell1 = (String) o1.elementAt(0); 
        String elementAtCell2 = (String) o2.elementAt(0);
        return elementAtCell1.compareTo(elementAtCell2);
    }
 };
```

This is my mocking data to be retrieved from model.getDataVector();

```
 Vector vector = new Vector() {
        {
            add(new Vector() {
                {
                    add("KEYA");
                    add(100);
                    add(1.1);
                }
            });
            add(new Vector() {
                {
                    add("KEYC");
                    add(11);
                    add(2.2);
                }
            });
        }
  };
```

So you call it like this, before you send your data to your persistence layer:

```
Collections.sort(vectorData, COMPARATOR_BY_KEY);
```